# Are Log messages and System.out.println calls visible once an Android app is published?

Tags: android, apk

I have many calls to `Log.d()` and `System.out.println()`, which I have used for debugging, in my Android application. Are these log messages still visible to anyone who runs the production apk?

Comment: Not only are they visible, they are executed code which slows down your app and blocks until done.  Best to remove before live.  Just remove the import Log from each class and you will immediately see the calls to log for comment out in case needed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. it is visible to others and retrievable using tools. 
You can pro grammatically check if it is in debug mode by following code,

```
 if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "xxxx");
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all log messages are still logged into standard Android logcat, even in release builds.

Answer (score 1):

All `Log` messages still visible to anyone who runs the production apk so you can create a custom class for print all the `Log`

```
public class MyLog {
     public final boolean ENABLE_LOG = true; // or ENABLE_LOG = BuildConfig.DEBUG

     public static void d(String tag, String msg) {
        if (ENABLE_LOG){
            Log.d(tag, msg);
        } 
     }
     public static void e(String tag, String msg){
        ...
     } 
     ...
}
```

and use

```
 MyLog.d("TAG","test"); // instead of Log.d("TAG","test")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are.  They are indeed.